# jQuery - Campo com no máximo 4 dígitos e completar com 0 à esquerda

Tags: jquery

Preciso de um campo em que possa ser inserido no máximo 4 números e, caso o usuário insira menos que 4 dígitos, os 4 dígitos sejam completados com zeros na frente, além de não aceitar valores como 0, 00, 000 ou 0000.

Fiz o código abaixo definindo uma máscara de 4 dígitos com o `input mask` e fazendo as devidas verificações para remover o valor digitado caso seja um dos valores citados acima (0, 00, 000 ou 0000) ou completar com zeros caso seja válido, porém não consegui identificar o motivo de o mesmo estar limpando o valor digitado ao tirar o foco do campo após digitar um valor válido, ao invés de completar com zeros à esquerda ou manter o valor digitado.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $("#numero").mask("9999");
    $("#numero").bind("change focusout", function (){
       var num = $(this).val();
       if (num == 0 | num == 00 | num == 000 || num == 0000){
          $(this).val('');
       }
       else{
          while (num.size < 4){
             num = 0 + num;
             $(this).val(num);
          }
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

Número <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" maxlength="4"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem que setar a option `autoclear: false`.

E seu if deve ser: `if (num == '0___' || num == '00__' || num == '000_' || num == '0000')`

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $("#numero").mask("9999", {
      autoclear: false
    });
    $("#numero").bind("change focusout", function (){
       var num = $(this).val();
       if (num == '0___' || num == '00__' || num == '000_' || num == '0000'){
          $(this).val('');
       }
       else{
          num = num.replace('_','').replace('_','').replace('_','');
          while (num.length < 4){
             num = '0' + num;
             $(this).val(num);
          }
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

Número <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" maxlength="4"/>
```

Comment: Pois é, mas fazendo somente essa alteração não está limpando o `input` ao inserir somente 0, 00, 000 ou 0000 e tirar o foco do campo, além de não estar completando o campo com os zeros à esquerda ao inserir um número válido.

Comment: Da uma olhada de novo.

Comment: Agora só não está completando com zeros à esquerda ao inserir um valor válido, por exemplo, 21.

Comment: Alterei mais uma vez

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Já tinha quebrado bastante a cabeça com isso e nada de funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

No `if`, remove os demais zeros, compara apenas com um zero `num === 0`

Ai no else, você substuí por isso:

```
// Transforma o valor do input num array, e automáticamente coloca um zero pros valores q não forem imputados
var arr = n.toString(10).replace(/\D/g, '0').split('').map(Number);
// Transforma o array numa string
var newNumber = arr.toString();
// Add o valor no input, removendo as virgulas.
$(this).val(newNumber.replace(/,/g,''));
```

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui fazendo as alterações citadas, porém está inserindo os zeros à direita do número inserido, ao invés de inserir à esquerda.
Além disso, gostaria de manter o código atual, apenas corrigindo o(s) erro(s) existentes e entendendo onde errei na lógica feita.

Answer (score 1):

Cara fiz um exemplo para vc.

> - **1** - Não precisa utilizar o **Mask** para isto pois vc já está setando **maxlenght** no Html.
> - **2** - O seu código só tinha um pequeno erro, na linha do **while** para pegar o tamanho não é **size**, mas, sim **lenght**.

```js
$("#numero").on("change", function(){
   var num = $(this).val(); 
       
   if (num == 0 | num == 00 | num == 000 || num == 0000){
      $(this).val('');
   }
   else{
      while (num.length < 4){
          num = 0 + num;
          $(this).val(num);
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

Número <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" maxlength="4"/>
```

Comment: Mas sem a máscara o campo passa aceitar outros caracteres que não sejam números, o campo deve ser preenchido somente com números. Se digitar 'd', por exemplo, ai com os zeros à esquerda, fica '000d'.

Comment: Mas se é só numero que quer é só colocar o input do tipo **number**. Não vejo necessidade de se carregar um plugin inteiro na página só para isto.

Comment: Já havia feito o teste com o `input` do tipo `number` antes, porém, se colocar o tipo como  `number`, em alguns navegadores não funciona a questão de completar com zeros à esquerda (Firefox, por exemplo).

Comment: Estranho, pq eu estou usando exatamente o **Firefox** e está inserindo os zeros normalmente.

Comment: Provavelmente você está fazendo o teste com o código atual (com `input` do tipo `text`), ai funciona, mas se colocar como `number` não funciona no Firefox, pelo menos aqui no meu Firefox 61.0.2 (última versão) não funciona.

Comment: Leandro, estou em cliente e o firefox dele é tão velho que aceitava os zeros mesmo do tipo number :]. Jóia que conseguiu resolver